# Get the version of the C libraries installed on an AIX server

Tags: aix

How can I get the version of the core C libraries installed on an AIX server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "lslpp" command would give you what you need, or even "smitty software".

```
lslpp -al
```

Will you show you all software packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

Select a file from C libraries (ie : gcc) do this :

```
lslpp -w /path_to_file/file
```

This will return a fileset, with this fileset do :

```
lslpp -l myfileset
```

If no fileset is return your, maybe your libraries is rpm packages.